# Two Spring MVC / Maven modules in one project

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I try to make a JavaEE application with 2 and more Spring MVC modules. Before I had WebSuite module, that have Web and DB modules

```
<modules>
    <module>../UBDB</module>
    <module>../UBWeb</module>
</modules>
```

In the DB module are all classes that work with database; in the web module - Spring MVC for views.

But now I need to re-organize my project. I need Maven managed modules, that will consist of different business logic. For example: I need one module that will have controllers and views to manage accounts, another module to create orders, another module for blog etc. (something like CMS). **All of these modules need to be on Spring MVC.**

But how do I need organize my pom.xml files to make it?

Answer (score 1):

For a webapp, we always loose our time with maven module to think we have a nice separation... that's useless.

Create an account-parent with

Account model
used by Account dao
used by Account service
used by Account controller

Do the same for all the group you wanna do.

Then create a single module app : MyWebApp. It contains just config, properties and add all the controllers in runtime.

You will loose your time while releasing modules, updating dependencies, ...
I worked this way untill last year.

Comment: I know about it. But I really need to have such maven modules.

Comment: Sorry for u but I was serious... you can work with the model I gave you :)

Comment: I already have such model. But, as I said, I need to re-organize it)

Comment: I don't understand, why don't you just merge X-model, X-DAO, X-Service and X-Controller into X and do the same for Y, Z,... Sorry but I'm lost Oo

Comment: what does mean X? It is maven module? Or just packadge. The main idea is, that people will by some modules. And maven can help us with it. For example they by modele A,C,F. And in my pom file I just write <module>A</module> ..... And it provide me all that I need

Answer (score 0):

So, sorry for late answer, but I found solution.
I have one module suite - that I use to get all modules in my project

```
<modules>
    <module>../news</module>
    <module>../blog</module>
    <module>../suite</module>
</modules>
```

Also it have `<packaging>pom</packaging>` property
Description news and blog are quite similar 
We can package it like jar files.
So, as I sad, I whanted to have some CMS system. How it works. I copy all nessesary modules to some directory. For example I will create site with news and blog module. So I copy there suite module, news and blog module(news and blog module are Spring MVC apps. Suite just pom.xml file). Then I create new directory (site module). In pom.xml of it I set

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

then in suite module I ad line for it.

```
<module>../site</module>
```

So I have 3 SpringMVc applications. 2 of them (news, blog are my modules, that I can set to different projects. Site - new module. It will be deploeed like Jar file This module different for different projects) and suite just to get all modules together.
And then mvn clean package.

Hope It will help for someone